# Umbraco iFrame macro not rendering in browser

Tags: xslt, iframe, macros, umbraco

I'm a bit of a newbie with Umbraco and simply want to put iFrames in. I followed what seems to be a popular XSLT solution which permits me to add in a macro:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:seoChecker.MetaData="urn:seoChecker.MetaData" xmlns:PS.XSLTsearch="urn:PS.XSLTsearch"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets seoChecker.MetaData PS.XSLTsearch ">
 
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="location" select="/macro/location"/>
<xsl:variable name="width" select="/macro/width"/>
<xsl:variable name="height" select="/macro/height"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <iframe src="{$location}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
Sorry, your browser does not support IFRAMES
</iframe>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I then added this macro into the content editor. However, when it's is viewed from a browser there are just tags < and > with UMBRACO_MACRO and some of the alias details inside.

The one thing I tried, to set one of the config settings to FALSE (TidyEditorContent), doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work or anyone know if there might be an alternative solution?

Thanks in advance
Iain​

Comment: Please include some code that you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: You can't have macros inside macros, so if a macro is being used to render the content with the macro in it, it will fail to render :-/

Comment: I've added in the XSLT to illustrate. Hope that helps

Comment: Are you inserting the macro into a rich text editor?  If so then you may have to use `umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent(...)` when rendering the content in your view.  See [this thread](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/6994-XSLT-RenderMacroContent--#comment-25557) for an example.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for this it looks promising! However, I wasn't joking when I said I was a newbie :-) Where *exactly* does this code snippet go - I've gotta hunch it will work though. Thanks, Iain

Comment: I got this to work eventually by running the code from a 'clean' page to which I linked users from the original page. Turns out we have several different page templates and most of them were themselves using macros to render. Therefore the macro was trying to render from within another macro. Doing this on an untemplated page rid me of that problem and the iFrame displayed perfectly.